# How to translate entity in the views footer

Tags: views, entities, i18n-l10n

I am creating a multilingual site. I have views and when it was created, I added to the footer entity (node/22). Next, I created a translation of this content and now changed id (node/45). How to specify the settings views to display different node corresponding to the user's language?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With views php module you could add php in footer instead of entity. Sample untested code:

global $language;
if ( $language-> language='en'){
$n=node_load(22);
echo $n->title; //or any other field
} else ...

A more elegant way is to use a view attachment and put another view in the footer